# Gravity of dark matter

Tags: gravity, spacetime, universe, relativity, dark-matter

1. Why call it dark matter not invisible matter? (or 'The Force') (or 'ether' like we used to)
2. Since time is bunk (thanks Douglas Adams) and space is bunk (thanks Einstein et al) why is anyone really surprised that measurements of celestrial movements viewed billions of years after they happened across the untold number of stretching space miles produces some tricky math?
3. Clearly I am struggling to take the presence of $3$ times the mass of the observable stuff in the universe existing as virtually undetectable other stuff largely on faith. Is there any (*real* science) work being done to try and disprove dark matter theory?

Ta

Comment: -1. What searching have you done to look for answers? eg http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+is+dark+matter.

Comment: 1) They can't call it "ether" because ether has already been disproved since Morley-Michelson's days; 2) No one is surprised in  that sense;  tricky stuff was expected. But there are several hypothesis that need to be validated/invalidated through experimental measurement. 3) It's not undetectable; if we do the math/simulations for normal masses we get some deviation from what we would have expected. Solving  this discrepancies gave rise to the concept of dark matter.

Comment: Employing some constructive criticism (instead of flagging the post twice): Dark matter has nothing to do with ether (look up Michelson-Morley or just ether). Cosmological measurements are precise and understood to a frightening degree; not to an absolute degree, obviously, but not to the non-existent degree your second point implies (don't look up special relativity, general relativity or cosmic microwave background; it'll take too long). [cont.]

Comment: Some people do like to put a mystical spin on dark matter, many others don't; its discovery came as a surprise and there are many points backing it (look up dark matter). As about testing it or examining it under a different light, it's not only MOND (mentioned in the answer) that tries to do so. See e.g. https://phys.org/news/2016-09-spiral-irregular-galaxies-current-dark.html Bottom line is not everyone in physics is as dumb as you imply.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter (pun not intended) of fact, yes! There is absolutely real work being done to try and disprove the existence of dark matter. One of the more publicized areas of research is something called [Modified Newtonian Dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics) or MOND for short. Now it should be noted that there is actually some very compelling and *real* evidence for the existence of dark matter. So much so that we can't simply say "Yeah, we got the math wrong" in the science world. Instead, those who don't like the idea of dark matter any more than you are attempting to modify existing theories of mechanics and gravity such that it no longer requires dark matter. This has met with a few successes and a few failures, but work continues nonetheless.

The reason we called it "dark" matter is because it doesn't emit any light or heat or anything and because we don't really know exactly what it is. The dark describes not only how it interacts with light, but also our state of enlightenment with respect to it (okay, that pun was intended).

In terms of our measurements, nobody is surprised that the math is tricky. However, we had these models of gravity and how it works. Our models are perfectly good for many different systems; the Solar system, Earth, even the cosmic scales of the expansion of the universe. We expected that if our models were good enough to predict things on all these scales, they should properly predict how galaxies rotate. They failed, however (sad trombone). But good news! If there exists some other form of matter that we can't see, then it works out perfectly. It also worked to fix other problems in cosmology, more than just astrophysics. Thus the schism: some scientists said "I just can't believe there is that much matter that we can't see" and worked on things like MOND. Other scientists said "The data agrees with us if we allow this other type of matter; why shouldn't there be a type of matter we can't detect?"

You can probably tell I'm a dark matter supporter. Sorry if I've brought too much bias into my answer. There are 4 fundamental forces. There are particles out there that don't interact with the strong force and the weak force; why couldn't there also be a particle that doesn't interact with the electromagnetic force? So I say to myself "I don't know everything already. I'm willing to admit there may be things out there that are different from anything I've experienced before. So if it fits the data, let's go with it and see what happens". That said, I can't fault anyone for going with MOND. If everyone followed the same theory, there'd be nobody to tell us when we're wrong (and we need that).